# Java bitwise operators, what is <<=, is it the same as <<

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

int x = 5;
x <<= 1;

int x = 5;
x << 1;

Is there any difference in these two?

Comment: One difference is that the second one does not compile!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  With `int x = 5; x <<= 1;`, the second statement modifies `x`.  With `int x = 5; x << 1;`, the second statement computes a value but does not modify `x`.  This is exactly the same as the difference between `*` and `*=` or `+` and `+=`.

In fact, the second pair of "statements" won't compile, as `x << 1` isn't a valid Java statement.